# Python list of dict sorting move all zero at bottom

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of dictionary which I am sorting using multiple keys.

Now I want to push all the elements that have zero rank (rank is a key)

**basically rank 0 must be at bottom**

```
mylist =  [ 
{
    "score": 5.0,
    "rank": 2,
    "duration": 123,
    "amount": "18.000",
},
{
    "score": -1.0,
    "rank": 0,
    "duration": 23,
    "amount": "-8.000",
},
{
    "score": -2.0,
    "rank": 0,
    "duration": 63,
    "amount": "28.000",
},
{
    "score": 2.0,
    "rank": 1,
    "duration": 73,
    "amount": "18.000",
},
]


from operator import itemgetter
sort_fields = ['rank', 'duration']
sorted_list = sorted(mylist, key=itemgetter(*sort_fields), reverse=False)

 print(sorted_list)
```

current output

```
[{'score': -1.0, 'rank': 0, 'duration': 23, 'amount': '-8.000'}, {'score': -2.0, 'rank': 0, 'duration': 63, 'amount': '28.000'}, {'score': 2.0, 'rank': 1, 'duration': 73, 'amount': '18.000'}, {'score': 5.0, 'rank': 2, 'duration': 123, 'amount': '18.000'}]
```

expected output

```
[{'score': 2.0, 'rank': 1, 'duration': 73, 'amount': '18.000'}, {'score': 5.0, 'rank': 2, 'duration': 123, 'amount': '18.000'},{'score': -1.0, 'rank': 0, 'duration': 23, 'amount': '-8.000'}, {'score': -2.0, 'rank': 0, 'duration': 63, 'amount': '28.000'}, ]
```

Comment: What is your expected output exactly?

Comment: And what exact *logic* too?

Comment: @Julien it is a ranking data, where ranks from given based on score, if score is negative the rank is 0

Comment: try using reverse=True

Comment: @BendikKnapstad to get rank from 1 to n number.

Comment: If you want to overwrite the default sorting you can write a key function that returns a tuple where the first element is the overwrite like `(1, 0, duration)` for zero rank and `(0, rank, duration)` for others.

Comment: @BendikKnapstad it is the podium concept

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
mylist =  [ 
{
    "score": 5.0,
    "rank": 2,
    "duration": 123,
    "amount": "18.000",
},
{
    "score": -1.0,
    "rank": 0,
    "duration": 23,
    "amount": "-8.000",
},
{
    "score": -2.0,
    "rank": 0,
    "duration": 63,
    "amount": "28.000",
},
{
    "score": 2.0,
    "rank": 1,
    "duration": 73,
    "amount": "18.000",
},
]


sorted_list = sorted(mylist, key = lambda x: (x['rank'] if x['rank'] > 0 else float('inf'),x['duration']))
 
print(sorted_list)
```

Comment: Please add some explanation as to *why* you’ve chosen this solution and how it’s designed to work.

Comment: itemgetter not need import

Comment: Here we have use float('inf') - if rank < 0 then we set rank value to infinite large value with the use of float('inf'). so we know infinite is greater than any other numbers so it comes at last.

Answer (score 1):

You should make the key function return a tuple of values based on the precedence of the sorting criteria. Since the first of your sorting criteria is in fact whether the rank is zero, make that test the first item of the tuple. Then you got the rest, namely the rank and the duration, correctly in order:

```
sorted_list = sorted(mylist, key=lambda d: (d['rank'] == 0, d['rank'], d['duration'])))
```